# vb6 error 380 Datepicker, bust just in certain dates

Tags: datepicker, vb6, runtime-error

Im having a problem with a datepicker on vb6, but this jus happen on certain dates, for example 31/01/2017, but with another dates it works fine.

[image: error image]

I appreciate the help

Comment: I like that you think we know all the error codes from a 19 year old, obsolete product and dont translate the error message for us.  Invalid property value means what it says - it probably has to do with the format/layout of the data being read.

Comment: Thaks for your answer, but i have to use this obsolete product because a costumer wants to keep using his old software. The format of the date that im reading is (dd/mm/yyyy) same as the datapicker, the error jump only when the date is 31/01/2017

Comment: It would be useful to inspect the value of rcsAux.Fields("xf3ch4") and let us know what it is.

Answer (score 3):

This almost certainly has to do with how you are setting the date in the control.

For instance if the control's value is ANY month that does not have 31 days then you will get that error. Trying to set the control to 31/02/2017 would cause an error 380.

There are two approaches you can take to fix this.

1. Reverse the order you set the date components.

   ```
   dtFecha.Year = Year(fcsAux.Fields("xf3ch4"))
   dtFecha.Month = Month(fcsAux.Fields("xf3ch4"))
   dtFecha.Day = Day(fcsAux.Fields("xf3ch4"))
   ```
2. Set the `Value` property instead of the date components. `dtFecha.Value = "31/02/2017"`

   ```
   dtFecha.Value = rcsAux.Fields("xf3ch4").Value
   ```

The first approach ensures the month is always appropriate for the day. The second approach sets the entire value at one shot and should be a valid date.

Comment: I use third-party controls, but I believe the standard date picker control does have mindate and maxdate properties.  If the above does not resolve your issue, I'd check those settings.

Comment: Thank you so much Bill, Option number 1 solved the issue.